# Prove that $E,F$ and $I$ are Collinear points.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a arbitrary triangle.
And $E,F$ and $I$ points such that :

$$\vec{AE}=\dfrac{2}{3}\vec{AB}~,~\vec{BI}=-\dfrac{1}{3}\vec{BC}~,~ \vec{AF}=\dfrac{1}{3}\vec{AC}$$

**Question**

Prove that $E,F$ and $I$ are Collinear points.

**My attempts**

I want to write a vector  $\vec{FE} $in terms of vector $\vec{FI}$ ( parallels)

Mean that in need find a scalar $k$ such that
$\vec{FE} =k × \vec{FI}$

But I can't find it! Where is thé idea.

Comment: Can you write what $\vec{EF}$ is (And also for $ \vec {FI}$), in terms of $ \vec{OA}, \vec{OB}, \vec{OC}$? (Or any other system that you want to choose. Maybe $\vec{AB}, \vec{AC} $ might be simpler).

Comment: Let me try.....

Comment: Hint: $\vec{AE}=\frac23\vec{AB}\implies E=\frac23B+\frac13A$

Comment: @robjohn then what ? Can you explain more please.

Comment: Compute $F$ and $I$, in terms of $A$, $B$, and $C$, in similar ways. There should be a relation among the representations of $E$, $F$, and $I$ that one can use.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to have a picture:

[image: geometry math stackexchange 4846663]

The solution using vectors is now easier to follow:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\overrightarrow{IE}
&=
\overrightarrow{IB} + \overrightarrow{IC}
=
\bbox[lightyellow]{
\frac 13\overrightarrow{BC} + \frac 13\overrightarrow{BA}
}
\\[3mm]
\overrightarrow{EF}
&=
\overrightarrow{EA} + \overrightarrow{AF}
=
\frac 23\overrightarrow{BA} + 
\frac 13
\underbrace{\overrightarrow{AC}}_
{\substack{=\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}\\=-\overrightarrow{BA}+\overrightarrow{BC}}}
=
\bbox[lightyellow]{
\frac 13\overrightarrow{BA} + \frac 13\overrightarrow{BC}
}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so $\overrightarrow{IE}=\overrightarrow{EF}$, the three points $I,E,F$ are collinear and $E$ is the mid point of the segment $IF$.

Comment: A solution using Menelaus is also possible.